# Datepicker: How to popup datepicker when click on edittext using C# xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-datepicker

How to show a date picker popup on Edit Text click or focus event in Xamarin.Android ?

Answer (score 15):

Try something like this for Xamarin.Forms :

```
public class SamplePage : ContentPage
{
    public SamplePage ()
    {
        var editText = new Entry {
            Placeholder = "Select Date.",
        };

        var date = new DatePicker {
            IsVisible = false,
            IsEnabled = false,
        };

        var stack = new StackLayout {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
            Children = {editText, date}
        };

        editText.Focused += (sender, e) => {
            date.Focus();
        };
        date.DateSelected += (sender, e) => {
            editText.Text = date.Date.ToString();
        };

        Content = stack;
    }
}
```

---

---

***Edit :***

Try something like this for Xamarin.Android :

**MyLayout.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**MyLayoutActivity.cs**

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Widget;

namespace AndiNative
{
    [Activity (Label = "MyLayoutActivity", MainLauncher = true)]            
    public class MyLayoutActivity: Activity
    {
        private static EditText editText;

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.DatePickerTest);

            editText = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.editText);

            editText.Click += (sender, e) => {
                DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
                DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, OnDateSet, today.Year, today.Month - 1, today.Day);
                dialog.DatePicker.MinDate = today.Millisecond;
                dialog.Show();
            };
        }

        void OnDateSet(object sender, DatePickerDialog.DateSetEventArgs e)
        {
            editText.Text = e.Date.ToLongDateString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have  to create a class.. what about the click event code

Answer (score 11):

For those of you who like MVVM. This is the MVVM implementation in Xamarin Forms. I've used Event to Command behavior here. You can get more on that from this link
[Xamarin Event to Command Behaviors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/behaviors/reusable/event-to-command-behavior)

**Xaml**

```
    <Entry Text="{Binding DateOfBirth, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Image Source="button.png" WidthRequest="39">
        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OnSelectDOBCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ., Source={Reference DOBPicker}}" />
        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
    </Image>
    <DatePicker x:Name="DOBPicker"
                Date="{Binding SelectedDOB}"
                IsEnabled="True"
                IsVisible="False">
        <DatePicker.Behaviors>
            <behaviors:DatePickerSelectedBehavior Command="{Binding DateSelectedCommand}" EventName="DateSelected" />
        </DatePicker.Behaviors>
    </DatePicker>
```

**View Model Code**

```
OnSelectDOBCommand = new RelayCommand<DatePicker>(FocusDatePicker);
DateSelectedCommand = new RelayCommand(SetDateOfBirth);
```

Now the function definitions

```
    private void FocusDatePicker(DatePicker obj)
    {
        obj.Focus();
    }
    private void SetDateOfBirth()
    {
        DateOfBirth = SelectedDOB;
    }
```

Hope this helps someone

**Update 11/11/2016**

The other alternative is to to use [ACR.Userdialogs](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs) simple and straightforward. Declare your ICommand

```
 OnSelectDOBCommand = new RelayCommand(ShowDatePicker);
```

Next define the function ShowDatePicker

```
private void ShowDatePicker()
{            
   UserDialogs.Instance.DatePrompt(new DatePromptConfig { MaximumDate = MaxDate, OnAction = (result) => SetDateOfBirth(result), IsCancellable = true });
}
```

And the set date of birth function

```
private void SetDateOfBirth(DatePromptResult result)
    {            
        if(result.Ok)
        {
            DateOfBirth = result.SelectedDate.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
        }

    }
```

The best part, you dont need any special Xaml at all. You can hook it to any button.

Allan should be given an award or something

Comment: getting Error: 'behaviors' is an undeclared prefix.

Comment: Yes, that's probably because you're just copy pasting and haven't read through my post. You need to create a custom behavior. Open the link I've shared, it will tell you how to create an EventToCommand behavior.In this case, you need to create a custom behavior for the DatePicker

Comment: How can i hook the UserDialogs.Instance.DatePrompt to a icon?

Comment: I think with the new version of XForms they have provided a ImageButton. Previously I would use the TapGesture to hook up a function and then invoke UserDialogs.Instance.DatePrompt

Answer (score 1):

```
 <EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/datePickerText"
    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
    android:textColorHint="@color/textColor"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    local:MvxBind="Value Format('{0:dd MMM yyyy}',Date)" />
```

property in viewmodel-

```
    private DateTime _date = DateTime.Today;
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get
        {
            return _date;
        }
        set
        {
            _date = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Date);
        }
    }
```

Inside my Class-

```
      private EditText datePickerText;
      private DatePickerDialogFragment dialog;
      protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.report);

        var dp = new MvxDatePicker(this);
        dp.SpinnersShown = true;
        dp.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
        datePickerText.Focusable = false;
        datePickerText.Text = ViewModel.Date.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");

        datePickerText.Click += (sender, args) =>
        {
        if(datePickerText.Text == "")
  dialog = new DatePickerDialogFragment(this, DateTime.Now,this);
       else
  dialog = new   DatePickerDialogFragment(this,Convert.ToDateTime(datePickerText.Text), this);

  dialog.Show(this.SupportFragmentManager, "date");
        };

        datePickerText.TextChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            ViewModel.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(datePickerText.Text);
        };
    }

  public void OnDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int   dayOfMonth)
    {
        datePickerText.Text = new DateTime(year, monthOfYear + 1, dayOfMonth).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    }
```

> *here it takes the default date for today orelse it changes to date selected by user*

Comment: @ratnamanjariswain -Accept my answer if it helped you.You have asked the question for xamarin.android using MVVM so the solution will help you !!! Best regards.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I found all the answers interesting and useful to varying degrees, nothing quite covered it.  Here's how to do it for plain old Xamarin.Android.

```
public class MyActivity : MyActivityBase
{
    private int _dateViewId { get; set; }
    private DateTime _myDate { get; set; }

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.activity_my);

        InitDateField ();
    }

    private void InitDateField ()
    {
        var rootLayout = FindViewById (Resource.Id.your_root_xaml_layout);
        rootLayout.AddView (GetNewDateView ());
    }

    private View GetNewDateView ()
    {
        var view = new EditText (this);
        view.InputType = InputTypes.DatetimeVariationDate;
        view.Hint = "Insert date";

        view.Id = View.GenerateViewId ();

        view.FocusChange += DateField_Click;
        view.Click += DateField_Click;

        return view;
    }

    private void DateField_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var view = (sender as EditText);

        if (view.IsFocused)
        {
            _dateViewId = view.Id;

            var date = DateTime.Today;

            // NB. The month needs translating here for the datepicker.
            var dialog = new DatePickerDialog (this, OnDateSet, date.Year, date.Month - 1, date.Day);
            dialog.Show ();
        }
    }

    private void OnDateSet (object sender, DatePickerDialog.DateSetEventArgs e)
    {
        // Store the date value for use in code.
        _myDate = e.Date;

        // Display the date in the desired format.
        var dateView = FindViewById<EditText> (_dateViewId);
        dateView.Text = e.Date.ToString ("dd/MM/yyyy");
    }
}
```

The datepicker dialog is triggered in either of two ways: -
 1. Tap directly on the date field.
 2. Arrival by tabbing Next in the keyboard whilst focused on the previous field.

Because the OnDateSet() method doesn't have prior knowledge of the EditText.Id, the Id is stored when triggering the datepicker ready to be used when updating its value afterwards.